# Under what condition is the constant dereferencing operator called?

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, dereference

I have a simple class

```
class Array
{
public:
    Array();
    ~Array();

    // Dereferencing operators
    int operator[](std::size_t index) const;
    int& operator[](std::size_t index);
}
```

My question is, under what condition is `int operator[](std::size_t index) const` called? How can I force C++ to call `int operator[](std::size_t index) const` instead of `int& operator[](std::size_t index)`? What would happen if I only implement one of the operators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, under what condition is int operator[](std::size_t index) const called?

when it's called on an instance of Array that is const

> How can I force C++ to call int operator[](std::size_t index) const instead of int& operator[](std::size_t index)?

cast the mutable instance of the array to a const reference

> What would happen if I only implement one of the operators?

If you only implement the const one, you won't be able to write to a subscript using `operator[]`.

If you only implement the non-const one, you won't be able to read a subscript of a const instance of an Array.